# awk: using external variables from bash

Tags: bash, awk

I am using awk inside of the bash script to print a new file contained the name of the variable defined in bash

```
#!/bin/bash
file_name='test.log'
awk -v file="$file_name"  '
    BEGIN {
        print "@ subtitle \"file\""
       }
```

in that case the awk prints

```
@ subtitle "file"
```

instead of the expected output

```
@ subtitle "test.log"
```

Comment: See [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a variable in a string as-is but you can concatenate between a string and a variable like so:

```
print "@ subtitle " file ""
```

In this case, the empty string `""` is useless, but it is just as an example. So you can just get rid of it and it will behave same with/without it.

```
print "@ subtitle " file
```

In your case, you want something like this:

```
print "@ subtitle \"" file "\""
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

```
file_name='test.log'
awk -v file="$file_name" 'BEGIN{ print "@ subtitle \"" file "\"" }'
```

Output:

```
@ subtitle "test.log"
```

Answer (score 2):

In your script `file` variable is inside the double quotes hence it is just printed as string instead of referencing as a variable.

You can consider `printf` for formatted output:

```bash
awk -v file="$file_name"  'BEGIN {printf "@ subtitle \"%s\"\n", file}'

@ subtitle "test.log"
```